# How to show menubar in figure matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I used some comment in below to disable the menubar in figure. Now, I want to display it again. I could not find the way to do it. Could you guide me how to show it in figure again

This is what I tried to disable menubar

```
iptsetpref('ImshowBorder','tight'); 
set(0,'DefaultFigureMenu','none'); 
set(0,'Default');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for the option `'DefaultFigureMenu'` is `'figure'`. The other option, as you have noticed, is `'none'`, which will disable the menu bar. This and other information about figure properties may be found [in the documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html).

The menu bar reappears in any new figures you open once you assign the value back to its default setting:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureMenu','figure');
```

As a side note, setting properties with first argument `0` makes the property value changes [global](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) (i.e. they apply to every figure), at least for the duration of your current MATLAB session.